# Django/South - Possible to migrate data from SQLite to MySQL?

Tags: django, django-south

I have developed a Django App using SQLite and now I need to migrate it to MySQLl.

MY question here is if there is a way to migrate all the data from SQLite to MySQL. The SQLite database have many data that will be a pain to migrate by hand to the MySQL. South will help to migrate the schema only or can help also to migrate the data?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) command to dump *SQLite* data:

```
./manage.py dumpdata app1 app2 app3 ... > dump.data
```

Then, use [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) command to load the dumped data to *MySQL*:

```
./manage.py loaddata dump.data
```

Comment: Sometimes I get "... is not json serializable" :(

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu, Please post a separated question (with contextual information).

Comment: For example in my object there is some datetime field and some customize field.... Then JSON can seriallize object